# How to update data stored in XML using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am using the following program to update the data which is stored in xml document using C#.

I have the two fields named `username` and `password`. If i try to insert the data, it will successfully be added.

My problem is when I try to update the data which is already stored in xml document. I am not able to update the record. So how can I update the record in XLM document using C#?

I have the following exception `NullReferenceException` which is originated in this line:

```
root.ReplaceChild(newCd, oldCd);
```

`Button1_Click` adds the data, `Button2_Click` updates the data.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connection();      
    }

    protected void Connection()
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(@"D:\vijay.net\xmlstorage\XMLFile.xml");
        XmlNode xmlnod = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("records");
        XmlNode xmlrec = xmlnod.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "record", ""));
        xmlrec.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Username", "")).InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
        xmlrec.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "password", "")).InnerText = TextBox2.Text;
        xmldoc.Save(@"D:\vijay.net\xmlstorage\XMLFile.xml");
        Response.Write("Successfully saved in xml file");
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"D:\vijay.net\xmlstorage\XMLFile.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();

        XmlNode oldCd;
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("/catalog/cd[Username='" + TextBox1.Text + "']");
        XmlElement newCd = doc.CreateElement("cd");
        newCd.SetAttribute("Password", TextBox2.Text);

        newCd.InnerXml = "<Username>" + this.TextBox1.Text + "</Username>";
        root.ReplaceChild(newCd, oldCd);
         doc.Save(@"D:\vijay.net\xmlstorage\XMLFile.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the XmlDataSource control, it does all the work for you... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be an **incompatibility between the XML document and the XPath expression** used to select the node to modify.

Based on the code in the `Connection()` method the resulting XML structure will look something like this:

```
<records>
    <record>
        <username>SomeUsername</username>
        <password>SomePassword</password>
    </record>
</records>
```

In the `Button2_Click` event handler, you're selecting the `/catalog/cd` node based on the value of its `Username` attribute:

```
oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("/catalog/cd[Username='" + TextBox2.Text + "']");
```

which returns `null` because that doesn't reflect the actual XML structure. You need to change the XPath expression to select the `oldCd` node based on its content instead:

```
oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("//username[contains(., '" + TextBox2.Text + "')]");
```

Comment: oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("//username[contains(., '" + TextBox2.Text + "')]"); if i use like this i have face the same error.

Comment: Could you post the actual XML that's being loaded?